# Office.auth.getAccessToken() is not working in Outlook Web. Error 13006

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, access-token, office-addins

The call to `Office.auth.getAccessToken({ allowSignInPrompt: true, allowConsentPrompt: true, forMSGraphAccess: true }).then(console.log);` fails with the following response.

```
{
    "name": "Error occurred in the authentication request from Office.",
    "message": "An unexpected error occurred in the client.",
    "code": 13006
}
```

I am not sure what i am doing wrong. I am pretty sure this used to work for me.
In my manifest if have the following configuration. I have re-consented to the app as admin.

```
<WebApplicationInfo>
<Id>myappId</Id>
<Resource>api://localhost:3000/myappId</Resource>
<Scopes>
    <Scope>User.Read.All</Scope>
    <Scope>User.Read</Scope>
    <Scope>profile</Scope>
    <Scope>openid</Scope>
</Scopes>
</WebApplicationInfo>
```

Comment: Have you looked up 13006 in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/troubleshoot-sso-in-office-add-ins?

Comment: I have logged out and restarted my browser twice. Even restarted my computer.
I have checked that Modern Authentication is enabled on the o365 account

Comment: Does your code work in Outlook desktop?

Comment: @flexxxit can you please confirm since when you started facing the issue? also please confirm if there was any recent manifest changes made for the add-in?

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT Yes there was a recent manifest change.
I am not really sure when the issue started...but I think it has been a long while. Perhaps a year now. If it is related to not having increased the version number on the manifest file then I can try verifying that.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an issue in Mozilla Firefox at least in version 120.0 64-bit version I have tested in.

I do not have any issues in Google Chrome Version 119.0.6045.199 (Official Build) (64-bit).

My suggested solution is to use another browser or wait until Microsoft have fixed their library to work in all browsers.